# PAB webserver not working

Tags: plutus, plutus-pab

Trying to connect to the PAB webserver on port 8080 gives: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080`

Output from running `cabal exec MyPAB`:

```
[INFO] Slot 0: TxnValidate b135806142f3d020fc68e9e72fa6e8e7c8fce34b2a0f17fd23b633641f58944a
[INFO] Starting MyPAB PAB webserver on port 8080. Press enter to exit.
[INFO] Starting PAB backend server on port: 9080
```

How may I fix the problem?